# Hbase rowkey salting when number of regions is changed

Tags: hadoop, hbase, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

In HBase to avoid the hotspotting of time series data, salting mechanism is applied to distribute the data evenly.
We can pre-split the table to `number_of_regions` and apply the formula to get the salted prefix `salt = key.hashCode() % number_of_regions)`.

The new rowkey will be `new_row_key = salt+key`

`number_of_regions` is not static and will increase with more load. My question is, when it happens, will this strategy work to distribute data evenly. Or I need to check the number of regions every time before I build the salt prefix ?